# Tomcat HTTP Status 404 - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource... With Spring boot and Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I used Spring boot 3.0, Tomcat 10.1 and Java 19. My pages are HTML. When running with Tomcat, my page was not found, as in the picture.
[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGawL.png)

[This is my Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf0gH.png)

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.schmersal.tabela</groupId>
    <artifactId>tabeladinamica</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tabeladinamica</name>
    <description>Template de tabela de dados</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What else could be missing from the configuration? I already changed something in the controller, I already looked the properties and preferences of Spring Boot.

Comment: Try to add actual code instead of image. Please provide a reproducible code.

Comment: You have `return "redirect:/reportes/login";` - but I don't see a mapping for that - only a mapping for `@GetMapping("/login")`. `/reportes/login` does not equal `/login`. I don't know if that will fix your problem, because there is no [mre] in the question, and only a [screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) of code.

Comment: Hello. My RequestMapping is @RequestMapping("/reportes") and after the @GetMapping("/login"). Therefore is /reportes/login .

Comment: I've tried with Tomcat 9, 10 and 11. In version 9 and 10 the address is not found and in version 11 it gives an error when loading the file.